# ADC Calibration - Vdd calculation

Tags: adc, stm32

In documents and lots of online sources there is a formula as follows,

$$  Vdd = 3.3V * \frac{VREFINT_{CAL}}{VREFINT_{DATA}}$$

But I cannot get why CAL value is in the numerator and RAW data is in the denominator. I have this logic in my mind,

In the factory, producers used a preknown/fixed 3.3 V as Vdd and then they get this reference CAL value from ADC. But in reality, my Vdd may be different because of non-idealities. So I read Vref_int channel via my ADC and it gives me `RAW`. I get the `CAL` value by reading the device memory address provided by manufacturer. ADC reading and voltage level has a direct relationship. So, I conclude that;

`3.3 V ------> CAL(from device memory)`

`x V   ------> RAW(read from Vref_int)`

Then, `x * CAL = 3.3 * RAW`

So, `x = 3.3 * RAW/CAL`  should be my formula to get my current Vdd value so that then I know that a maximum ADC reading (4095 for 12 bits reading for ex.) corresponds to `x` volts.

However, in the above formula it states that `x = 3.3 * CAL/RAW`.

Please help me with that, thanks.

My board is STM32F4-DISC.

-------------------- edit ------------------------------------

With all my thanks to the ones who answered, I now understood(I hope) what is going on and want to explain here in detail.

First, what is what :

`VREFINT_{CAL} or CAL : The ADC reading of the manufacturer from Vref_int when an exact 3.3V Vdda is used (unitless, 12 bits integer)`

`VREFINT_{DATA} or RAW : The ADC reading of the user from Vref_int when the Vdda is unknown (unitless, 12 bits integer)`

`V_{DDA} : Kind of the voltage base for our MCU, when you give a digital high output then it should be exactly equal to Vdda (unit = volts)`

Now,

> 1- In the factory, the manifacturer gets the ADC conversion data from
> the **Vref_int** channel and stores it into a memory location as a
> 12-bit integer. $$  \frac{{VREFINT_{voltage}}}{3.3(V_{DDA})}= \frac{{VREFINT_{CAL}(stored\,value\,,CAL)}}{4095} \quad (1)$$
> The logic is simple here, 4095 for 3.3V and **CAL** for Vref_int.
>
> 2- When you want to calibrate your voltage level, since you don't know
> your exact voltage base level, you read the **Vref_int** yourself and
> get another ADC conversion value(**RAW**), let's call it $$VREFINT_{DATA}$$
> Then $$  \frac{VREFINT_{voltage}}{V_{DDA}(unknown)}= \frac{{VREFINT_{DATA}(measurement\,of\,user\,,RAW)}}{4095} $$

Since $$VREFINT_{voltage}$$ is fixed, replace it with its equivalent from eqn. (1).

Then you can see that the equation yields to $$V_{DDA}(unknown) = \frac{3.3*CAL}{RAW}$$

Finally, you can use this Vdda value as your voltage reference(base) on your calculations.

This edit may include some mistakes, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ADC reading and voltage level has a direct relationship.

The ADC reading on the V<sub>REFINT</sub> channel and V<sub>DDA</sub> have *inverse* relationship.

An ADC reading is the ratio of the measured voltage to V<sub>DDA</sub>, scaled up to 4095 (the maximum value that can be expressed on 12 bits). E.g. if you applied V<sub>DDA</sub>/3 to an ADC input, the result would be 4095/3=1365.

So, the conversion result, ADCx = 4095*V<sub>ADCINx</sub>/V<sub>DDA</sub>

You cant't measure V<sub>DDA</sub> directly, because if you apply a voltage equal to V<sub>DDA</sub> to an ADC channel, the conversion result is always 4095.

V<sub>REFINT</sub> is a fixed voltage generated inside the MCU, around 1.2 volts. When you convert the V<sub>REFINT</sub> channel of the ADC, you get the ratio of this voltage to V<sub>DDA</sub>, i.e. 4095*V<sub>REFINT</sub>/V<sub>DDA</sub>. Note that V<sub>DDA</sub> is now in the denominator. If the supply voltage goes down, the conversion result goes up, and vice versa.

Because V<sub>REFINT</sub> is not an exact voltage source, they measure it in the manufacturing process, using a good stabilized 3.3V supply, and write the conversion result (V<sub>REFINT<sub>CAL</sub></sub>) in the system memory area.

Now if you'd read the V<sub>REFINT</sub> channel, and got the exact same value that's stored in the system memory, it would mean that V<sub>DDA</sub>=3.3V, like in the factory calibration process. This is also what the formula in the question gives you when V<sub>REFINT<sub>CAL</sub></sub> = V<sub>REFINT<sub>DATA</sub></sub>.

Answer (score 2):

VREFINTcal is the only known value. The value of VREFINT, when measured with a known good 3.3V Vdd.
If you divide `data` with `cal` you know how many bits Vdd is off, assuming VREFINTcal is still valid.

If VREFINTcal is 1000, and data is 1020, this means you've measured VREFINT to be 20 bits **higher** than it's supposed to be. Indicating a **lower** Vdd value.
Hence 1000/1020 = 0.98. A 2% difference. Thus 3.3*0.98 = 3.24 V.

You are not measuring the change in VREFINT, but the change of the ADC reference.

[image]
*[link to drawing](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=Untitled%20Diagram.drawio#R5Vhdb5swFP01PC7iKwQeG5Z22lRpa6TucXLxLVgzGBknwH79zDDhK2RNlTYae4nMsX19fc7h2kSz%2FLi44yiN7hkGqpk6LjTro2aaru3J3wooa8Dx3BoIOcE1ZLTAlvwCBeoK3REMWW%2BgYIwKkvbBgCUJBKKHIc5Z3h%2F2zGh%2F1RSFMAK2AaJj9DvBIlLbWuot%2FglIGDUrG7rqiVEzWAFZhDDLO5C10SyfMybqVlz4QCvuGl7qebcTvYfEOCTiJRO%2BOMuo%2FPzg338TZB8%2Fxij4oX9QUfaI7tSGVbKibBiABN9URMqnhCUSXEcipvLJkM1xEioi4B6vKqU7YDEIXsoBectmQ2bUIbLBOFAk8%2B2rgZSo4SHcYYWvjMhMTF35z2zkUPYzbb0fImM7HoCa1WXvL4HcQRyBeAhiFEc2OrtuoT%2FanKGTOXed7EvpNAhkmO8rlHWWUAFFWUaCf0srwxlQvPIWy8u8VUdCTeglGURlZ1haDchOJO1OrdQaoI55UTvY87fDCzR89cv7ZnY4nMpTdhjPsK5ioOXIQI8Ya6ZDpYjrJy5bYdWyFs0tozWWgEL0rZQJzn6Czyjj7SnxTCgdQIiSMKn8KC0HEl%2FvgQsiL0U3qiMmGFfLrPOICNimKKjWzOUNUGKc7RIM1ab0U%2FatYkJx0sBTDmsuhx2D20cMPiz9XS%2F36v65ojjHRdGthTVfFYZlf3VlEVZjER42t01dmKcExrAGXVkDd6SBrXvOfAUYVqJr8%2B%2F9b%2FwPLwhvdxLIx%2FbbvD7N2z84rM1v)*

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, i will try to understand it. But in my location, imgur is blocked, if you have time can you please upload image via another source?

Comment: @muyustan sure, see my edit

Comment: thanks again, but I cannot get it, what is exactly the vrefintcal value? When I read the vrefint channel on my device with adc, what value do I get? Is it the voltage applied to my board?

Comment: "*If VREFINTcal is 1000, and data is 1020, this means you've measured VREFINT to be 20 bits higher than it's supposed to be*", do you really mean *bits* here? Or do you mean that it is *offset* by 20?

Comment: @HarrySvensson Is there another unit for the value that any ADC provides?

Comment: @muyustan VREFINT is an internal bandgap reference, usually 1.2V or something alike. When you measure it you get what a quantification of that voltage in 12 bits relative to Vdd. (Vref+)

Comment: @Jeroen3 I think "value", as you said in your response to me is the closest. Bits are bits, with 20 bits you can make a number close to 1 million (2^20). I don't think it is 20 bits higher. I think It's higher by 20, or higher by 20 values., or offset by 20. And the bits required to represent 1000 and 1020 are 10 bits. It's like apple and oranges.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between ADC input voltage and output value is:

$$IN = \frac{V_{REF} * OUT}{ 4095 }$$

Therefore:

$$VREFINT = \frac{3.3*CAL}{4095} = \frac{V_{DD}*RAW}{4095}$$

Therefore:

$$V_{DD} = \frac{3.3*CAL}{RAW}$$

Comment: by "output code" what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I should say "output value".

Comment: hey, now I get the first equation clear. For that equation `IN` should be a 12-bit ADC reading and `OUT` is a the measured voltage right? But you wrote "the relationship between adc **input voltage** and output value". Then I understand from this sentence that `volts * volts / unitless = volts` which does not sounds right. Is it also a mistake or am I missing something? Thanks anyway

Comment: @muyustan Oops, my bad, I've corrected the equation. `IN` is the measured voltage and `OUT` is the 12-bit ADC reading.